# How do i center the heading in my form heading?

Tags: html, css, position

I am using the center tag to center a heading in my form, "Please register your details".  It works perfectly like I want it to but it fails the validation. Does any one else know what I could use?

```
<form method = "post" action = "mailto:info@ncirl.ie">

<fieldset>

<legend><center><b>Please Register Your Details</b></center></legend>
```

Comment: What is the validation results you are getting?

Comment: The `<center>` tag is removed as of html5

Comment: That tag was deprecated by cavemen...

Comment: @DSG Make that html4: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/html4-ref/article.php/3460291

Comment: @Shomz In HTML4 it was deprecated, HTML5 removed

Comment: @DSG Sorry, misread it :)

Comment: Sly Raskal  It says "document type does not allow element "CENTER" here; missing one of "APPLET", "OBJECT", "MAP", "IFRAME", "BUTTON" start-tag".

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `<center>` which will force your design to be centered forever, you should deal with it in CSS:

```
form legend { text-align:center;font-weight:bold; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your heading into a div and text-align:center it. If I am not wrong center has been deprecated. All this stuff should sit in your css.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  Please register your details
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the width of the label element by default is 100%, the display is still inline. Without using the block display AND specifying a width: `margin:0 auto;` will **NOT** work.

The only correct use for this instance is:

```
<legend style="text-align:center;">Please Register Your Details</legend>
```

Setting a width for this would be unwise, as the physical font width can vary between browsers, and "over compensating" the width will result in offsetting the text from the center.